# Bash variables - Any extract tricks based on the order?

Tags: bash, variable

Instead of:

```
var1=foofoo
var2=barbar
var3=jarjar
```

Is there some trick I can to get the variable based on the order it was set in?

```
var=foo
var=bar
var=jar
```

> echo $var2

```
bar
```

(I know the `var` variable is overwritten each time!)

I'm seeking a trick since I constantly change the order of 20+ of these variables.

It will be much easier if I just rearrange them by top-to-bottom order.

Comment: you constantly change the order of those 20 variables? then you don't want a list of names, or even an array of names, you want a *shiftable* parameter set as you would get with a function. just define a function that works with `$1` and `$2` and `$3` and so on.

Comment: Hey Mike, I get what you mean, however, in my situation, I will also be relying on additional variables afterwards, so I'm thinking choroba's suggestion for an array will work best for me. Thanks for the tip regardless

Comment: `fn(){ set -- "$3" "$2" "$1"; printf %s\\n "$@"; shift; printf %s\\n "$@"; }; fn var1 var2 var3` prints `var3\nvar2\nvar1\nvar2\nvar1`. in my opinion people tend to try to put too much value in a name - what's usually important is what is done with its value. the shell is *very* good at argument mangling, but is a none-too-reliable database. just define a function which *does* something with its arguments, rather than trying to find a way to *store* information so you might figure out what to do with it later.

Comment: I recently got into functions, and I have never heard of the shift command. Thanks for exposing it to me, it's amazing how many possibilities there are to do things. I'm thinking an array fits my situation more, but if you have any final thoughts feel free to share them :)

Comment: nah. you do what you like. it was just a suggestion/observation. in my opinion shell names are too much abstracted too much of the time, but it is only my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using distinct variables, use an array:

```
var=(
      foo
      bar
      jar
    )
echo "${var[1]}"   # bar
```